# Amazon RDS: PostgreSQL Performance Poor

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

We use postgresql as a backend for Apache. We are planning to migrate our PostgreSQL from an EC2 instance (m1.xlarge +500GB volume/Ubuntu) to RDS.  However, in our testing on the same sized instance (m1.xlarge) on RDS the performance is dramatically slower (perhaps a third of the EC2 instance).

Both instances are in the same availability zone as the Apache server.  Considering that the RDS instance will cost almost double of the EC2 instance, what steps or configuration changes should I try to boost the performance of the RDS instance? There are some hints to creating a VPC into which both the web server and RDS instance should be dropped. Does the VPC idea have legs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: VPC wont affect performance. Although you need more information. Have you configured both instances the same way? Are you using provisioned io in other case?

Comment: @datasage, we aren't using provisioned IO on any of the instances. Since RDS is a horse of a different color, they can't be configured the same way, per se. But, they are the same size, have similar volume sizes, etc.

Comment: You should be use the same config. Some config vars may be limited, but most should be available. The goal would be to create as similar environments as possible, so you can narrow down the cause of the discrepancy.

Comment: Also check the results of `EXPLAIN` in both environments.

Comment: As it turns out, the problem was not with RDS, specifically. The problem was with pg_restore/pg_backup not properly handling the indexes when we copied the data to RDS. Thanks @datasage for that EXPLAIN idea. It led us to the solution: REINDEX [DATABASE]

Comment: Please post that as an answer-to-self with some details.